# HERE Map armeabi-v7a libraries removed when im adding armeabi file(C library) Is there something missing with my Android.mk file?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, arm, armv7, eabi

Hello i'm new to NDK and C/C++ development with android application. i'm having problem in my android application in compiling android application with c/c++.. I added some custom libraries for my sqlite. Could anyone explain what's happening to my project and is there something that i need to configure with my MK file? i added this to my mk file **APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a**

> Here is my Android.mk file

```
APP_PLATFORM := android-8

#WHAT DO I NEED..
APP_ABI := armeabi armeabi-v7a
#TARGET_ARCH     = arm
#TARGET_ARCH_ABI = armeabi-v7a

LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ExtFunc
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := extension-functions.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += sqlite3.c
LOCAL_SHARE_LIBRARIES := sqlite3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)


include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE    := ProximityAPI
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ProximitySearch.c
LOCAL_SRC_FILES += sqlite3.c
LOCAL_SHARE_LIBRARIES := sqlite3

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

> [image: Here is my Library Structure]
>
> When i started running my project the armeabi-v7a libraries
>   automatically removed in compilation.

I used NDK R10b

To make things clear the two library is working in different project but when i combine them it removed my HERE-Map Libraries under the armeabi-v7a in compiling my android application.

Hope someone could help me i'm confused..

Thanks!

Comment: _"is there something that i need to configure with my MK file?"_ For anyone to be able to determine that you should probably include your current Android.mk in your question.

Comment: To make things clear, APP_ABI has to be put in Application.mk.
If you have to specify architecture in Android.mk, here is an example :
`LOCAL_SRC_FILES := 3rdparty/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/liba.so`

Answer (score 0):

APP_ABI should go into your Application.mk file within the jni folder. It might not exist by default so you might have to create one. Also, if you are building only for ARM there is no need to specify that explicitly. If you are looking to target multiple architecture like x86 you could add that to you APP_ABI parameter.